# Is there a way to check if 2 aggregates are equivalent?

Tags: c++, c++17

Lets suppose that I have 3 aggregates:

```
struct User
{
    int age {};
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

struct Car
{
    int power {};
    std::string name;
    std::string owner;
};

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    std::int age {};
};
```

I would define that 2 aggregates are equivalent if they have the same number of member fields, of the same type and in the same order.

For example, `User` and `Car` are equivalent: 3 fields: `int, string, string`, but `User` and `Student` are not: one is `int, string, string` while the other is `string, string, int`.

Implication of this functionality I would say are obvious, you would be able to very easy copy 2 unrelated but similar aggregates.

Edit: aggregates are coming from different places, I can't change them, or make them inherit from same class, or anything else. I was interested if, with all C++11/17 generics, type-traits, SFINAE magic, etc, this would be possible at all.

EDIT2: I just discovered [`std::is_layout_compatible()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) which probably does what I have in mind, but it's scheduled to be released in C++20.

Comment: And can you please elaborate on the whole "equivalent" bit? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need to know if two structures are "equivalent"?

Comment: I have no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3), therefore is an aggregate

Comment: What's wrong with `User u; Car c = { u.age, u.name, u.address };`?

Comment: Side note: Your definitions are lacking the semicolons after closing braces.

Comment: @Aconcagua: thx, fixed. Imagine I have many structures, each with many fields. Manually assignment is worse than, for example ```User u; Car c = *(Car*)&user```. But I can only do this if I ```static_assert(are_equivalent(User, Car))```

Comment: Even if possibly(?) legal, I don't feel comfortable with your casts... In given example, it looks pretty much that it's rather `Car::owner` that should refer to `User::name`! `User::address` and `Car::name`, on the other hand, appear entirely unrelated. What makes you sure that these two API match *that* exactly that you really simply can cast? My proposed variant, even if more work, forces you to check for each type if assignments really are correct. Of course, you should pack this stuff into conversion functions to avoid code duplication...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `std::string` is not an aggregate, but these structures are: https://godbolt.org/z/nzKgA0.

Answer (score 3):

Structural equivalence (ignoring semantic equivalence) is not a feature you can check without compiler-support.

You need *some* type of basic reflection, or something pre-packaged liks [C++20 `std::is_layout_compatible`](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#rel).

Your specific case is interesting as all members are public, allowing you to use C++17 [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to get references to the members, though you have to know the number of elements, and whether they are references.

```
template <class T, class T2, class U, class U2>
bool structurally_equivalent_helper(T&& a, T2&& a2, U&& b, U2&& b2) {
    return std::is_same_v<decltype(a2), decltype(b2)>
        && ((char*)&a2 - (char*)&a) == ((char*)&b2 - (char*)b);
}
template <class T, class U>
bool structurally_equivalent3(T&& a, U&& b) {
    auto&& [a1, a2, a3] = std::forward<T>(a);
    auto&& [b1, b2, b3] = std::forward<U>(b);
    return structurally_equivalent_helper(a, decltype(a1)(a1), b, decltype(b1)(b1))
        && structurally_equivalent_helper(a, decltype(a2)(a2), b, decltype(b2)(b2))
        && structurally_equivalent_helper(a, decltype(a3)(a3), b, decltype(b3)(b3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this without any extra boilerplate, you need reflection, which is unfortunately not in C++ yet (it might make it to C++23, though).

You can get most of what you want by adding a `tie` function to each object.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

struct User
{
    int age{};
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    auto tie() { return std::tie(age, name, address); }
};

struct Car
{
    int power{};
    std::string name;
    std::string owner;
    auto tie() { return std::tie(power, name, owner); }
};

struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    int age{};
    auto tie() { return std::tie(name, address, age); }
};

int main() {
    auto b1 = User().tie() == Car().tie();
    auto b2 = User().tie() == Student().tie(); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Tie is too permissive (conversions), and means adapting each candidate. Overall, your answer isn't much concerned with layout but functionality. Still, a valiant effort.

Answer (score 1):

[magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) library makes it relatively easy:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/pfr.hpp>

template <std::size_t ...I, typename F>
constexpr bool all_of_seq(std::index_sequence<I...>, F func)
{
    return ((func(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})) && ...);
}

template <typename A, typename B>
inline constexpr bool is_equivalent_v = []
{
    namespace pfr = boost::pfr;

    if constexpr (!(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B) && pfr::tuple_size_v<A> == pfr::tuple_size_v<B>))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return all_of_seq(std::make_index_sequence<pfr::tuple_size_v<A>>{}, [&](auto index)
        {
            constexpr int i = index.value;
            return std::is_same_v<pfr::tuple_element_t<i, A>, pfr::tuple_element_t<i, B>>;
        });
    }
}();
```

First, we make sure both structures have the same size and the same amount of fields:

```
sizeof(A) == sizeof(B) && pfr::tuple_size_v<A> == pfr::tuple_size_v<B>
```

Then, we compare field types:

```
std::is_same_v<pfr::tuple_element_t<i, A>, pfr::tuple_element_t<i, B>>
```

This solution is mostly equivalent to what @Deduplicator suggested, but it doesn't involve writing boilerplate templates thanks to magic_get.

Also, this implementation doesn't compare field offsets (because I don't think it can be done at compile-time), which makes it makes it less reliable: If struct fields have `alignas` on them, you can get false positives.

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

struct User
{
    int age {};
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

struct Car
{
    int power {};
    std::string name;
    std::string owner;
};

struct Foo
{
    int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_equivalent_v<User, User> << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << is_equivalent_v<User, Car > << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << is_equivalent_v<User, Foo > << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << is_equivalent_v<Car , Foo > << '\n'; // 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the types in advance, the simple solution would be providing description of all equivalence types you are using. For ex.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename... Args>
struct EquivalenceType
{};

template<typename T>
struct EquivalenceClass
{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool AreClassEquivalent()
{
    return std::is_same<typename EquivalenceClass<T1>::Type, typename EquivalenceClass<T2>::Type>::value;
}

struct User
{
    int age{};
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};

struct Car
{
    int power{};
    std::string name;
    std::string owner;
};

template<>
struct EquivalenceClass<User>
{
    using Type = EquivalenceType<int, std::string, std::string>; 
};

template<>
struct EquivalenceClass<Car>
{
    using Type = EquivalenceType<int, std::string, std::string>; 
};

int main()
{
    cout << AreClassEquivalent<User, Car>() << endl;
}
```

For every class you want it to be "equivalence comparable" you would need to provide the specialization of EquivalenceClass template.

One big downside of this would be maintaining consistency, for ex. after modifing User definition and forgetting to update it's EquivalenceClass.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but one of the things I want is to automatically detect changes in an aggregate, for example when getting a newer API version.